# Какой предлог использовать: С или ИЗ?

Tags: морфология, предлоги

Что будет более корректно употребить в конкретном словосочетании:
*книга* (?) *дополнением.* Тут должно быть "с" или "из"?

Comment: Полагаю, русский - не родной вам язык. Вопросы уровня РКИ ("русский как иностранный") лучше задавать здесь: https://russian.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

В конкретном словосочетании, конечно же, необходимо использовать предлог "с":
*книга* (с чем? творительный падеж) ***с** дополнением.*

Можно вспомнить о его плодотворном сотрудничестве с Норбертом Винером, одним из результатов которого стала **книга** Буша **с дополнением** Винера [20]. [В. В. Шилов. Ванневар Буш // «Информационные технологии», 2004.11.29]

Можно придумать контекст и с предлогом "из", но это уже будет родительный падеж.
Предположим, что в библиотеку поступили книги двумя партиями: сначала основная, крупная, а затем небольшая, дополнительная (предположим, по особому списку или спецзаказу).
Вот тогда о книге, поступившей со второй партией, можно сказать так:
*книга* (из чего? откуда?) ***из*** *дополнени**я***.

[Падежи. Предлоги. Вопросы](http://mou70.ru/images/AAAAAAAAAAA/1202/4a/cpravmat.PDF)

Answer (score 0):

**Книга с дополнением.**
Предлог "из" не имеет нужного значения.